# Is there a way to delete the duplicate from a table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

[image]

As you can see, the rows 2 and 3 are similar, and row 3 is a useless duplicate. My question is how can we delete row 3 only but **keep row2 and row4** at the same time.

Like this:

[image]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What if E2 is swapped with E3, which row is then "useless duplicate"? The definition of "duplicate" has to be very formal as some solumns constitute business key, some are attributes and it seems you want to preserve rows that contain non-null data over others.

Comment: Is the definition here: "If the `portCode`, `effectiveDate`, and`issueCOAName` columns are the same then of those rows keep only the record(s) with non-null benchmark columns"?

Comment: *"and row 3 is a useless duplicate."* yet the values to the last 2 columns differ, so it by definition isn't a duplicate. What defines the top row is the one to delete, not the bottom one?

Comment: By the way, Kenny, your real name is displayed in the top right of those screenshots; if you care (I assume you might, due to using a pseudonym here).

Comment: @JNevil You're right

Answer (score 1):

You don't have duplicates. If you had a heap table with identical records, then every value in one or more records would be the same.  One means of dealing with this would be to add an identity column.  Then the identity column can be used to remove some but not all of the duplicates.

In your case, you want to delete records if another record exists that is similar and perhaps has "better" data. You can use an EXISTS clause to do this. The logic below is not what you want, but it should give you the idea of how to handle this.

```
DELETE t
FROM MyTable t
WHERE t.BCT IS NULL -- delete only records with no values?  
    AND t.BCS IS NULL 
    AND EXISTS( -- another record with a value exists, so this one might not be needed?
        SELECT * 
        FROM MyTable x
        WHERE (x.BCT IS NOT NULL OR t.BCS IS NOT NULL)
            AND x.portCode = t.portCode 
            AND x.effDate = t.effDate
            AND LEFT(x.issueName, 26) = LEFT(t.issueName, 26)
        )
```